# Find/replace string that spans lines in a file with REBOL

Tags: html, replace, rebol, rebol3, rebol2

I have an HTML page, and  I need to replace a couple of lines in it. However, using `replace` can't seem to find anything bigger than a single line.

This is what I would like to replace (there are multiple instances of it in the page):

```
....
<div class="logo">
    <img src="resources/logo.svg" />
    <span>e</span>
    <span class="text">Market</span>
</div>
...
```

Here's the code I am trying, but it doesn't work:

```
index-html: read %index.html    

logo-div: {<div class="logo">
<img src="resources/logo.svg" />
<span>e</span>
<span class="text">Market</span>
</div>}

new-div: {...}

out: replace/all index-html logo-div new-div

write %index.html out
```

Including `^/` in my `logo-div` string to denote the newlines doesn't help.

How can I find this entire string?

*(I am using Rebol2, but I assume the functionality will be the same or very similar in Rebol3.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about `replace` but this is a good opportunity for `parse` to work well:

```
index-html: read %index.html
out: copy ""
new-div: "..."

;;parse rules

title: [
    {<div class="logo">} thru {</div>} (append out new-div) ;;appends replacement when it finds that class
]

rule: [
    some [
        title |
        copy char skip (append out char)  ;;copies every other char char
    ]
]

parse index-html rule

write %index.html out
```

Don't have the index file, but this should work.   Take some time to carefully study string parsing.  It is very powerful.

Comment: This works great! The only thing I needed to change was to use `parse/all` so I still had whitespace in my output. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @JamesIrwin I'll mention also that PARSE will "stringify" any TAG! elements it finds, as a dialect behavior.  So the rule could be more like **title: [<div class="logo"> thru </div> (append out new-div)]**.  Rebol's source notation is not compatible with all HTML this way, just tags.  So you'd have to write **<span class="text"> {Market} </span>**, for example, to splice the string in the middle there.  But it's still comes in handy.  Note also if you're unaware: [Rebol and Red SO  Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue you are facing is that of the variable number of spaces between elements. If you can trim out the whitespace, replace should work:

```
>> data: {
{    line 1     
{    line 2  
{    line 3
{    line 4   
{    <div>
{    line d1   
{    line d2
{    </div>
{    line 5    
{    line 6                   
{    }
== {
line 1     
line 2  
line 3
line 4   
<div>
line d1   
line d2
</div>
line 5    
line 6                   
}
old-div: {                
{    <div>
{    line d1   
{    line d2
{    </div>
{    }
== {
<div>
line d1   
line d2
</div>
}
>> new-div: {
{    <div>new line d1^/new line d2</div>
{    }
== "^/<div>new line d1^/new line d2</div>^/"
>> replace/all trim/all data trim/all old-div new-div
== {line1line2line3line4
<div>new line d1
new line d2</div>
line5line6}
>> data
== {line1line2line3line4
<div>new line d1
new line d2</div>
line5line6}
```

If you want to retain the HTML indentation, then parse as suggested by kealist would probably be the best option.